# Obtain the tabBarController title in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I'm using a `UITabBarController` in my app and I want to know the title of the item selected to adapt my view in consequence. Do you know how I can proceed ?

Thanks

Comment: can you please show your efforts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try: (from your `UITableViewController`)

```
NSLog("%@", self.tabBarController.selectedViewController.tabBarItem.title);
```

This will give you the title of current selected **Tab Bar Item**. If you wanted the title of current **View Controller**, you should use:

```
NSLog("%@", self.tabBarController.selectedViewController.title);
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
    UINavigationController *currentnavVC = [tabBarController.viewControllers [tabBarController.selectedIndex]];
UITableViewController *currentVC = [currentnavVC topViewController];
    NSString *title = currentVC.title;
```

Comment: I don't think it will work because I want to take the title from my UITableViewController

Comment: it will work as `UITableViewController` is inherited from `UIViewController`

Comment: So I should do that : `UITableViewController *currentVC = [tabBarController.tableViewController [tabBarController.selectedIndex]];
    NSString *title = currentVC.title;`

Comment: do you have navigationController ahead of tableVC

Comment: In my header I have that : `@interface ScheduleListTableViewController : UITableViewController`

Comment: No Sir in hierarchy have u embed a navigationVC in storyboard ahead of this TableVC

Comment: Oh sorry, misunderstanding, yes I have my tab bar controller then the nav controller and after my table view

Comment: Still not working, it unknown receiver tabBarController

Answer (score 0):

I did that :

```
NSString *title =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.tabBarController.selectedViewController.tabBarItem.title];
```

Thanks for your answers guys